# Using Volatility Framework with Linux memory dumps

Tags: linux, memory

I am using Volatility Framework 2.2 to anlayze a Linux memory dump.

This memory dump was taken from an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS x86_64 machine with the kernel version 3.5.0-23

I have the profile for it and you can find it at the link below.

http://www.sendspace.com/file/pqyipd

I have placed this zip file in the location: /volatility/plugins/overlays/linux

below is the output of the command:

```
python vol.py --info | grep Linux

LinuxUbuntu1204x64 - A Profile for Linux Ubuntu1204 x64
```

now I use this profile to analyze the memory dump:

```
python vol.py --profile=LinuxUbuntu1204x64 -f mem.dump linux_pslist
```

and I get a blank output!

```
$ python vol.py --profile=LinuxUbuntu1204x64 -f mem.dump linux_pslist
Volatile Systems Volatility Framework 2.2
Offset             Name                 Pid             Uid             Start Time
------------------ -------------------- --------------- --------------- ----------
```

it does not give me the list of processes

I have tried this with another memory dump as well and same output.

I am trying it on a linux memory dump provided in a recent CTF, ebCTF 2013 forensics challenge.

You can find the write up here:

http://blog.lse.epita.fr/articles/59-ebctf-2013-for100.html

I am using the same profile provided by this user however in my case it does not work.

Any idea why would I  get a blank output?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your "LinuxUbuntu1204x64" profile also for kernel 3.5.0-23? `grep`ping the memory dump provided by the challenge, indeed, confirms your words that the memory has been probably dumped on a system with 3.5.0-23 kernel:

```
$ strings ~/Downloads/memory.dump | grep "BOOT_"
    1099:BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=UUID=d45d9170-0f93-4ff4-b5a5-be89760c0d77 ro
    185123:Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=UUID=d45d9170-0f93-4ff4-b5a5-be89760c0d77 ro
    185205:Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=UUID=d45d9170-0f93-4ff4-b5a5-be89760c0d77 ro
    195710:[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=UUID=d45d9170-0f93-4ff4-b5a5-be89760c0d77 ro
    221017:ernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=UUID=d45d9170-0f93-4ff4-b5a5-be89760c0d77 ro
    236853:[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=UUID=d45d9170-0f93-4ff4-b5a5-be89760c0d77 ro
    260767:Jul 21 21:13:16 eindbazen kernel: [    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=UUID=d45d9170-0f93-4ff4-b5a5-be89760c0d77 ro
    262173:Jul 21 21:13:16 eindbazen kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=UUID=d45d9170-0f93-4ff4-b5a5-be89760c0d77 ro
    360508:Jul 21 21:13:16 eindbazen kernel: [    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=UUID=d45d9170-0f93-4ff4-b5a5-be89760c0d77 ro
    806187:Jul 10 20:07:18 eindbazen kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=UUID=d45d9170-0f93-4ff4-b5a5-be89760c0d77 ro
    806319:Jul 21 21:13:16 eindbazen kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=UUID=d45d9170-0f93-4ff4-b5a5-be89760c0d77 ro
    806342:Jul 10 20:07:18 eindbazen kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=UUID=d45d9170-0f93-4ff4-b5a5-be89760c0d77 ro
    2524180:bcode_jmp RTC=0x%x, iter=%d, REBOOT_STATUS=0x%x
    2525925:bcode_jmp RTC=0x%x, iter=%d, REBOOT_STATUS=0x%x
    2528767:bcode_jmp RTC=0x%x, iter=%d, REBOOT_STATUS=0x%x
    2566790:bcode_jmp RTC=0x%x, iter=%d, REBOOT_STATUS=0x%x
    2850450:BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic
    2874700:BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic
    2874702:BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=UUID=d45d9170-0f93-4ff4-b5a5-be89760c0d77 ro
```

Try `/linux/Ubuntu_12.04_x64_3.5.0-23-generic.zip` profile from here: [http://git.io/volatility-profiles](https://github.com/nikki-mccavee/volatility-profiles/blob/master/linux/Ubuntu_12.04_x64_3.5.0-23-generic.zip). You may also want to know how to create a profile by visiting the official how-to [here](https://code.google.com/p/volatility/wiki/LinuxProfiles). If you come up with some profiles, feel free to shove them into that [repo](http://git.io/volatility-profiles).

Firing up Volatility checked out from SVN (that would be `2.3_beta`) works well:

```
$ python ./vol.py -f ~/Downloads/memory.dump --profile=Linux_Ubuntu_12_04_x64_3_5_0-23-genericx64 linux_pslist
    Volatile Systems Volatility Framework 2.3_beta
    Offset             Name                 Pid             Uid             Gid    DTB                Start Time
    ------------------ -------------------- --------------- --------------- ------ ------------------ ----------
    0xffff88000f9b0000 init                 1               0               0      0x000000000aff1000 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000f9b1700 kthreadd             2               0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000f9b2e00 ksoftirqd/0          3               0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000fa48000 migration/0          6               0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000fa49700 watchdog/0           7               0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000fa4ae00 cpuset               8               0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000fa4c500 khelper              9               0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000fa4dc00 kdevtmpfs            10              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000fa68000 netns                11              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000fa69700 sync_supers          12              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000fa6ae00 bdi-default          13              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000fa6c500 kintegrityd          14              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000fa6dc00 kblockd              15              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000fb00000 ata_sff              16              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000fb01700 khubd                17              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000fb02e00 md                   18              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000db90000 khungtaskd           21              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000db91700 kswapd0              22              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000db92e00 ksmd                 23              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000db94500 fsnotify_mark        24              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000db95c00 ecryptfs-kthrea      25              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000d5f0000 crypto               26              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000d7a5c00 kthrotld             35              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000d7a2e00 scsi_eh_0            36              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000d7a1700 kworker/u:2          37              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000d7a0000 scsi_eh_1            38              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000d5f5c00 scsi_eh_2            39              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000d5f4500 kworker/u:3          40              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000d5f1700 binder               42              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000f011700 deferwq              62              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000f012e00 charger_manager      63              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000f014500 devfreq_wq           64              0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:32 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000ee35c00 jbd2/sda1-8          201             0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:33 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000ee30000 ext4-dio-unwrit      202             0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:33 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000ec7dc00 kworker/0:3          220             0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:35 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000ec78000 upstart-udev-br      288             0               0      0x000000000ada3000 2013-07-21 19:19:37 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000f2ddc00 udevd                332             0               0      0x000000000ef46000 2013-07-21 19:19:37 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000c291700 udevd                496             0               0      0x000000000c2a6000 2013-07-21 19:19:37 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000c292e00 udevd                497             0               0      0x000000000c2c1000 2013-07-21 19:19:37 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000c838000 kpsmoused            546             0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:19:37 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000c4c9700 upstart-socket-      638             0               0      0x000000000d939000 2013-07-21 19:19:38 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000ee31700 dhclient3            706             0               0      0x000000000f0fb000 2013-07-21 19:19:38 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000c4cc500 rsyslogd             720             101             103    0x000000000c600000 2013-07-21 19:19:38 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000c83ae00 sshd                 729             0               0      0x000000000bbce000 2013-07-21 19:19:38 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000c4cdc00 dbus-daemon          759             102             105    0x000000000c538000 2013-07-21 19:19:38 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000d1aae00 getty                822             0               0      0x000000000c641000 2013-07-21 19:19:38 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000c62c500 getty                827             0               0      0x000000000d98c000 2013-07-21 19:19:38 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000c839700 login                831             0               1000   0x000000000f28d000 2013-07-21 19:19:38 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000c83dc00 getty                832             0               0      0x000000000d9c1000 2013-07-21 19:19:38 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000c4cae00 getty                834             0               0      0x000000000c684000 2013-07-21 19:19:38 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000d0a4500 acpid                837             0               0      0x000000000c315000 2013-07-21 19:19:39 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000c83c500 cron                 839             0               0      0x000000000d9da000 2013-07-21 19:19:39 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000d1a9700 atd                  840             0               0      0x000000000c327000 2013-07-21 19:19:39 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000da11700 login                896             0               1000   0x000000000ae44000 2013-07-21 19:19:39 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000c514500 whoopsie             901             103             106    0x000000000dae3000 2013-07-21 19:19:39 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000bb15c00 bash                 1064            1000            1000   0x000000000c6f0000 2013-07-21 19:19:46 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000af90000 kworker/0:0          1313            0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:24:35 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000af94500 kworker/0:2          1314            0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:29:36 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000af91700 kworker/0:1          1315            0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:34:37 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000af95c00 kworker/0:4          1316            0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:35:46 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000af92e00 python2              1317            1000            1000   0x000000000c6fb000 2013-07-21 19:36:09 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000d0a5c00 bash                 1454            1000            1000   0x000000000d8c8000 2013-07-21 19:36:23 UTC+0000
    0xffff88000f9b4500 flush-8:0            1552            0               0      ------------------ 2013-07-21 19:36:28 UTC+0000
```